# Error while running the project in android(eclipse)

Tags: android

sir while i am running our project on android it gives an error then i start my emmulator again but still it shows an error:

[2010-12-23 12:45:25 - helloandroid.project] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front.

kindy help to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, that's a warning.

What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

May be your activity is running on the screen & again you are trying to run it from eclipse.
Please check that.

Comment: As i have restarted the emulator but sill i am facing the same problem

Comment: I think you have two emulator processes in your system. Please check taskmgr.

Comment: Yes Jett is right.Some times it is seen that two adb processes are running kill both them from taskmanager.

Comment: hello i want to know what is the basic idea behind we use classes in java